# Save button for view List in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, postback

In MVC3 view i have a table made by RadioButtons populated by entityObject:

```
@model IEnumerable<Table>  (View is made as "List")
```

Below i added a postBack "Save" button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyView", FormMethod.Post, new { ent = Model }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

And in controler i added:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<Table> ent)
{
    // do something
}
```

But is not right. How to correct the code to return all list in controler side.
Thx.

Comment: You forgot to add the code that generates the html input fields. The problem is probably in that code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the proper code to write the radio buttons in the view, otherwise they will never be submitted in your post request.

By the way, postback is a term used in webforms and not MVC.

The most voted answer for [ASP.NET MVC: Is postback still here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777179/asp-net-mvc-is-ispostback-still-here) provides an answer.