# Ispostback likething in MVC 4 ASP.Net Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

my webpage takes list from customer in the same time i want to display all records from temp_data. PROBLEM is i have to give same id's for table so that i can get the data based on the ID. So please tell something like Ispostback (webforms)  in MVC

I WANT TO RETAIN id variable to give same id but it changes on every post. Please help me

```
{

    RMS_DataContext db = new RMS_DataContext();
    Order cls_order = new Order();
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form, string btn_orders)
        { 

            switch (btn_orders)
            {       
                case "btn_temp":
                    Item item = new Item();

                    var ItemId = form["_OrderId1"];
                    item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault( x=> x.ItemId==ItemId );
                    cls_order.Add_Temp(id, item, Convert.ToInt32(form["quantity"].ToString())); 

                    return View();
                    break;

                    default:
                    return View();
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: can you show some code reference please..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Is IsPostBack still here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777179/asp-net-mvc-is-ispostback-still-here)

Comment: @sanjay   Code posted

Comment: you can make jquery ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You create a separate action in your controller to handle the `POST` action, which would essentially be a "Postback" from webforms. You would then handle any items in the POST which you would have handled in your Postback.

If you're handling validation, be sure to check `ModelState.IsValid` and return your model to your View again which should then display validate errors

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
   var model = new EditModel() { Id=Guid.NewGuid() };
   return View(model);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(EditModel model) 
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      // do stuff when valid
      return RedirectToAction("Index"); //or whatever when you're done saving, etc...
   }

   return View(model);
}
```

In your View:

`@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id);`

Comment: My case is of ADD ,  i generate GUID in string ID_ than in every insert i want to save the same ID_ so that i can get all data of this ID_ ,     string ID_=  Guid.NewGuid().ToString();   .... so when there is post it generates new id..... I want ISpostback liketheing to RETAIN this GUID

Comment: then use a Guid instead of int, and use that as your id, it'll always post with that in the url

Comment: just saw your edit... the Controller is not static, so Id will always contain a new Guid each and every time. You will need to either assign it on your model and hold it in a hidden field and post it along with your other data, or use my suggestion above

Comment: Can you just write some  code so that i can get your idea.

Comment: I updated based on your edit, stubbed code, losely based on your posted code

Comment: u can see that in my CREATE VIEW i have not binded any model because in my case there are several models to be used.... so how can i return a model in  my view