# ASP.NET page post back

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, webforms

In ASP .NET code, I see lot of `if(!IsPostBack)` checks.

Let's take an example of ASP.NET MVC, when request is made to a controller method for the first time, it serves a view, say it is a razor page in this case. In this first request the `IsPostBack` will be false.

Once the view is served by the controller, is the same controller method called again automatically without any user interaction? And this time `IsPostBack` will be true?

Or the controller method is only called on some user interaction, say user submits a form or something similar, then controller action method is called and the `IsPostBack` flag is true?

Comment: IsPostBack is a web forms concept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777179/asp-net-mvc-is-ispostback-still-here

Comment: I do not know about ispost back but Post Back means when  data(something that user has explicitly provides) has to be sent to the controller from the view.Like when submitting forms.

Comment: This question is tagged MVC and webforms. Which is it? If it is both, you need to clarify the question.

Comment: @SudeepShrestha - thanks, I'm new to web development. This is what I wanted to know as well. So PostBack is data being posted back to server by user or any other means.

Comment: @SteveGreene - thanks for you comment. I wasn't sure if this applies to MVC or web forms. but looks like this is only web forms thing.

Comment: What is confusing is you mention controllers - that is an MVC thing. Also, it is possible to mix the 2. Showing the code in question might help.

Answer (score 0):

IsPostBack is used to check if it is the first request or a result of user interaction e.g. a button click to submit a form

E.g. When you first load the page, you can make a database call and store values in cache. If the user posts the page back, you can check IsPostBack and load values from cache instead, saving a heavy resource call